# WEBRtc with WEB Audio Api

Tags: javascript, webrtc, web-audio-api, mediastream

I want to get track from webrtc and then play it, but my realization don't work. (Track's state is "live" but i dont hear audio.)
How can I do it without `HTMLAudioElement` and `new Audio`

```js
pc.ontrack = e => addTrack(e.track);
// ...
function addTrack(track) {
  const context = new AudioContext();
  const source = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(new MediaStream([track]));
  source.connect(context.destination);
}
```

Но Volume. But the next code is work:

```js
document.getElementById('audio').srcObject = stream;
```

This too:

```
function gotStream(stream) {
  const audioContext = new AudioContext();
  const mediaStreamSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource( stream );
  mediaStreamSource.connect( audioContext.destination );
}
const mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})
gotStream(mediaStream);
```

Comment: You define `arrTrack` instead of `addTrack`. Is it just a typo in your question or a bug in your code?

Comment: @giavac, typo in question.

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe I assume you're testing your code in Chrome. Unfortunately this is a long standing issue in Chrome which hasn't been fixed yet.

One of the bugs mentioning it in Chromium's bug tracker is for example this one: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=933677#c4

> It is a known issue that remote streams have to be assigned to a media element so that they play on web audio.

Comment: Hmm, you are right. In Firefox it work fine.
In Google i need firstly connect stream to Audio(srcObject), play&mute this audio. And only after it AudioContext will work. Thnx!